# Exception: Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator

Tags: java, log4j2, weblogic-10.x

Log4j : 2.6.1, Weblogic: 10.3.6 JDK: 1.7.x

I am getting below error while using log4j jars 2.6.1 in weblogic domain lib folder:

```
<Jun 25, 2016 7:36:49 AM EDT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below plugin to pom.xml resolve my issue. Basically if you want to put you jar in weblogic bundle dependencied in jar itself.

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
          </plugin>
```